# Is there a reference that describes Recurrent Neural Networks for NLP tasks?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, reference-request

I would like some references of works that try to understand the functioning of any kind of RNN in natural language processing tasks. They can be any work that tries to explain the functioning of the model by studying the structure of the model itself. I have the feeling that it is very common for researchers to use models, but there is still little theory about how they work in solving natural language processing tasks.

Comment: Did you do any research yourself?

Comment: I think that this request "works that try to understand the functioning of any kind of RNN in natural language processing tasks." is a bit broad. There are many NLP tasks. So, I suggest that you reformulate this post to ask a **more specific** question (maybe focus on a specific NLP task) or, at least, explain why you're interested in "all NPL" tasks.

Comment: Moreover, as suggested in the previous comment, there are several references on the web that already explain how RNNs work (such as [this](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)), even if you say "but there is still little theory about how they work" (which is incredible, as there are many resources explaining how RNNs work).